# What is x* when referring to the conjugate symmetry of a Fourier transform?

Tags: fourier-transform, symmetry

I'm learning about symmetry properties of the discrete fourier transform.
Any sequence x[n] can be expressed as: $x[n] = x_e[n] + x_o[n]$

- $x_e[n]$ is a conjugate symmetric component of the sequence ($x_e[n]=x_e^*[-n]$)
- $x_o[n]$ is a conjugate asymmetric component ($x_o[n]=-x_o^*[-n]$)

Each component is obtained using:

- $x_e[n] = \frac{1}{2}(x[n]+x^*[-n])=x_e^*[-n]$
- $x_o[n] = \frac{1}{2}(x[n]-x^*[-n])=-x_o^*[-n]$

I don't understand what the * operator is supposed to show? Is $x^*[n]$ different to $x[n]$, and if so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The star simply represent [complex conjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate), that is
$$ (a + bi)^* = a - bi. $$
Now you can proceed and verify all the identities given in your question.